# Bash скрипт для автоматического удаления файлов

Tags: ubuntu, bash

В линуксе я новичок. Установлена Ubuntu 18.04.

Мне необходимо настроить резервное копирование файлов. Архив автоматически создается отправляется через SSH на компьютер для хранения. Специально выделил для хранения жесткий диск. Если пройдет определенное количество времени, то диск заполнится этими файлами и нельзя будет скопировать новые.

Вопрос в следующем:
Как средствами `bash` написать скрипт, который смог бы определить достаточно ли места на жестком диске, и в случае наличия необходимого места - скопировать файл. Соответственно, если места недостаточно, то необходимо удалить самый старый файл или несколько файлов до достижения необходимого пространства, чтоб новый файл можно было скопировать?

---

В общем, решил для себя проблему следующим образом. Скачал скрипт который определяет размер папки и удаляет из нее самые старые файлы до тех пор, пока не будет выполнено условие размера. Вот код:

```sh
while [ "$(du -shb /media/bu3/backups_work | awk '{print $1}')" -gt 1000000 ]
do
  find /media/bu3/backups_work -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@\t%p\n' | \
      sort -n | head -n 1 | cut -d $'\t' -f 2-  | xargs -d '\n' rm -f
done
```

Comment: Может стоит посмотреть в сторону софта для бэкапов, а не городить свои костыли на `if\then\else`? Не, если интерес академиеческий, то конечно да.

Comment: По-моему, костыли тут использовать спецсофт. Как стрелять из пушки по воробьям. Уже решил для себя проблему. Перед копированием файла определяет размер папки. Если больше - трет самое старое до получения объема удовлетворяющего условиям. Нашел в интернете, плюс отредактировал.

Comment: Вам надо настроить Bacula. https://www.bacula.org/

Comment: @0andriy вместо 7zip ssh scp предлагаете ставить такого слона?

Comment: Да. Потому как для каждой задачи лучше выбирать подходящий инструмент. Сегодня вам хочется только того, чего в вопросе написано, завтра ещё чего-нибудь, а послезавтра выяснится, что по сути вы собственными силами изобретаете велосипед. Не стоит.

Comment: @0andriy спасибо. уже проходили. "сегодня вы стаканчик кинули. а завтра бутылку"

Comment: Рунет, такой рунет, за (полезный) совет и послать могут... Удачи вам!

Comment: @0andriy Спасибо. И Вам

Answer (score 1):

Есть замечательная команда `du` которая поможет вам в этом вопросе. Так-же неплохо почитать маны по `grep` и `awk`, которые помогают вытащить нужную инфу из иногда многословного вывода утилит. Ну надеюсь про перенаправление ввода вывода, конвейеры и вот это вот всё вы в курсе?

Comment: Нет. Не в курсе. Я новичок в линуксе. Мне нужен работающий скрипт Bash.

Comment: @ToD, заплатите фрилансерам, что ли...

Comment: @0andriy Звонкой монетой. ;-)

Comment: За всё, за всё это! Оу оооо!

Comment: а вы заплатите всем людям в интернете от которых вы узнали то, что знаете

Comment: @ToD, самому себе что ли? Нет, действительно был миллион людей, которые отвечали на мои вопросы, суть-то в правильности задания вопроса, и не в сиденьи на попе ровно, а в делании *домашнего задания*. Любое требование готовых решений -- это коммерция, а не учёба.

Comment: @0andriy я не буду с вами спорить. интернет полон разных решений. одни помогают, а другие нет, ссылаясь на то, что это коммерция. так было и есть и будет